# How to redirect an https site from www to non www

Tags: htaccess, 301-redirect, https, no-www

After adding an SSL certificate I want to 301-redirect all my site's URL variations to non-www ones. I tried creating a redirect from cPanel for all other variations.

Every other URL variations redirect except for `https://www.example.com`, this one does not redirect to `https://example.com`. Both URLs can be accessed and won't redirect to the non-www ones.

I've added canonical, Google has crawled and indexed both. Analytics gave a redundant hostname notification. I also tried redirecting from an htaccess file using these code:

```
# BEGIN SSL
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ https://example.com$1 [R,L]
# END SSL
```

and

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Both failed.

All I want is to redirect all URL variations, secure or non-secure, to `https://example.com` (non-www secure version).

Comment: Are directives in `.htaccess` files enabled with an [`AllowOverride` directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/core.html#allowoverride) in your server or virtual host config?

Comment: Incidentally, be aware that the default value for the `R` redirect flag is `302`. In your case, be sure to state `R=301` for each redirection, for your canonical URL to enforce quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Your **first code** has 2 errors in the `RewriteRule` directive:

- `^$` does not capture anything, so `$1` is always empty here.
- A slash is missing before `$1`, because if it could have captured something like `Foo.html`, the substitution URL would be of the form `https://example.comFoo.html`.

Your **second code** seems valid to me, although the `RewriteBase` directive is useless since your are using an absolute substitution URL. I do not understand why it does not redirect www-URLs to secured non-www URLs. Something must be interfering with this code.

**Finally**, in your case, for redirecting every alternative URLs to the secured non-www URLs, an adequate set of *Apache* directives for an `.htaccess` file could be:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Make sure that some of your *cPanel* redirection settings do not interfere with these directives.